# Randomly generating a 2D array with 0 and 1 numbers without using Numpy in Python

Tags: python

Randomly generating a 2D array with 0 and 1 numbers  without using Numpy in Python. It must include a spesific number of ones. eg: 8.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow, a webiste that is not a coding service. Please consult [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and share what you have tried.

Comment: I suggest to start from small thing. Could you manually create 2D array with just 0s and 1s?

Comment: How do you want to create a 2D `array` without `numpy`? For example a list of lists is not a 2D array.

Answer (score 3):

First create the data layout you want, e.g. `5 * 5 = 25` values with `8` ones and `25 - 8 = 17` zeros

```
shape = (5,5)
length = shape[0]*shape[1]
nr_of_ones = 8
data = [1] * nr_of_ones + [0] * (length - nr_of_ones)
data
```

Out:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Shuffle the data and reshape to desired 2D format

```
import random
random.shuffle(data)

[data[i:i+shape[1]] for i in range(0, length, shape[1])]
```

Out:

```
[[0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from random import randint

d = int(input("Enter array size: "))
o = int(input("Enter number of ones: "))

#Generate a 2D array of 0s
result = []
for i in range(d):
    row = []
    for j in range(d):
        row.append(0)
    result.append(row)
#Convert randomly selected elements to 1
for i in range(o):
    while True:
       r = randint(0, d*d -1)
       column = int(r % d)
       row = int(r / d)  
       if result[row][column] == 1:
           continue 
       result[row][column] = 1
       break
print (result)
```

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Thanks for your comment, I edited to handle that condition.